# TinyMCE - Unable to load the editor in vue front-end plugin page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, javascript, tinymce

I have this code in my plugin page that is created using vue 3.
I need to use the wordpress editor and I'v used the `wp_enqueue_editor()` function to load all the needed assets of tinyMCE.

in the vue app I have this code but I'm unable to load the editor

```
<template>
<div class="container-fluid mt-3 px-5">
    <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h4 class="text-uppercase fw-bold">
                Last messages
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-12">
            <hr class="my-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <h4 class="text-uppercase fw-bold">
                Demo message
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 mb-3">
            <label class="fw-bold text-uppercase mb-2">
                Demo object
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="message_title" placeholder="Oggetto comunicazione" id="comunication-title">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 mb-3">
            <label class="fw-bold text-uppercase mb-2">
                Destinatari
            </label>
            <div class="input-group w-100">
                <select class="form-select" name="" >
                    <option>-</option>
                </select>
                <button class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" id="submit-comunication">
                    Pubblica
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 p-0" id="message-editor" v-if="showEditor"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'App',
    data(){
        return {
            showEditor: true
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.initEditor();
    },
    methods: {
        initEditor(){
            console.log(restService.currentUser)
            if( restService.currentUser.roles[0] !== 'administrator' ){
                this.showEditor = false;
            } else { 
                console.log( wp.editor, window );

                wp.editor.initialize('message-editor', {
                    tinymce: true,
                    quicktags: false
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

</script>
<style scoped>

</style>
```

Is there something wrong into the configuration of the editor? If I log the window object or wp object I can see that they are loaded correctly. Any suggestion?